# Hide entry ID to increase security of a web app?

Tags: security

Over here in [symfony's tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/9), it says:

> **Hide all ids**
>
> Another good practice in symfony
>   actions is to avoid as much as
>   possible to pass primary keys as
>   request parameters. This is because
>   our primary keys are mainly
>   auto-incremental, and this gives
>   hackers too much information about the
>   records of the database.

Why is that so? And does it apply to all web apps?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exposing keys is a potential internal direct object reference risk. In essence, it's saying that if keys conform to a predictable pattern, they may be used against you in an attack. Of course other layers of security should prevent his (proper authorisation, in particular), but it's one more little layer of security. The concept is relevant to all apps which expose internal keys.

See [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 4: Insecure direct object reference](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/09/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-4.html) for more info.

Comment: If your security is properly designed, it shouldn't matter if you shout your IDs to the world. Only authorised users should be able to take advantage of it.

Comment: Yes, and if your security is properly designed you shouldn't need to hash your passwords or protect your DB logons either. As with all things security, it's a layering approach in order to minimise the risk of single points of failure.